# SSH doesn't work through mikrotik

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, nat, mikrotik

I have Mikrotik RB952Ui-5ac2nD. Everything is working fine.
But now, I found little problem.
I can not connect from LAN to any SSH in internet, but, when I'm connected without mikrotik, i havent any problem.

If I'm conecting to SSH in internet from mikrotik terminal, I will connect without probelms. But If I want connect from pc behind mikrotik I haven't got any response-

I have configured only nat masquarade in firewall.

Do you know, what I need to solve that, please?
Thank you

Comment: You must have a firewall rule that blocks traffic. Update your post with the result of "/ip firewall export" terminal command.